# Using ActionBarActivity instead of ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-actionbaractivity

my own activity extends the ListActivity for the following reason:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/h_exercises"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_add_exercise"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    style="@style/general_list_view" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/info_no_exercises_in_DB"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_add_exercise"/>
```

So if the Activity extends ListActivity and u got a view with id "@android:id/empty", the view will be shown if the list is empty.

But since my Activity needs an ActionBar i need to extend my Activity by ActionBarActivity. So is there a way to implement this scenario programmatically?

Maybe something like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {        
    if (listview.getCount()!=0){
        textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }         
}
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions

greets Pebbles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListFragment and put it inside an ActionBarActivity. ListFragment has built-in empty view feature.

Comment: thank you, this sounds smart. Ive never worked with fragments. I need the inflater for this, right? i always used setContentView...

Comment: To work with fragments, the approach you can use is: setContentView on the Activity with an empty FrameLayout, inflate the ListFragment in Activity's onCreate, and define own layout for that fragment, with its own lifecycle

Comment: thanks, guess u mean it like that one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtSfkAn22S8 ;)

Comment: okay that worked :) - thank you soooo much. was a nice learning lesson :)